# Filter that contains INC followed by a series of numbers

Tags: excel, filter

is it possible to custom filter in Excel so that I get the data that contain INC followed by a series of number? (numbers vary)

I would like to get data like:

Request raised (**INC12460031**)

email sent in order to set up SNOW ticket **INC12168408**

Excluding the following examples: INCorrect, INConvenience etc.

(...)37 hours are mentioned which seems to be **incorrect**.

Please accept our apologies for all the **inconvenience** caused.

Comment: I would use conditional formatting with `AND(Left(Cell,3)="INC",IsNumber(Right(Cell,1)*1))` and then filter so conditionally color formatted cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with an Advanced Filter.

[image]

The formula in E2 excludes items where the character following "INC" isn't a number greater than 0. Observe that the created MidString has a length of only one character. You could increase that number even to the point of including the entire word. Such an increase would ensure that numbers starting with zero aren't excluded.